# How i display index.js file onto the server in js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend

**I am trying to write a simple "Hello World!" on my index.js file, to which I receive a 404. However, when I type the same code in my app.js file, it works perfectly fine and I do not know why this is.**

My index.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var db = require('monk')('localhost:27017/');
var userData = db.get('user-data');
var app = require('express')();

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
 res.send("Hello world!");
});


module.exports = router;
```

My app.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = require('express')();
var path = require('path');
var port = require('port');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var hbs = require('express-handlebars');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes');

var app = express();

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
 res.send("Hello world!");
});


// view engine setupquire('express-handlebars');
const queryString = require('query-string');

app.engine('hbs', hbs({extname: 'hbs', defaultLayout: 'layout', layoutsDir: __dirname + '/views/layouts/'}));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

I expected "Hello World!" to appear on my server because of my index.js file, yet I get a 404 error instead. Like I said however, I do get "Hello World!" when I place the same code in app.js instead.

Comment: In `index.js` it should be `router.get..` since you're building routes you don't need `app` in that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake is in the index.js file. You have to export `router` instead of `app`.
So the last line must be changed to `module.exports = router;`